# Is One Web application effect on other web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

i have to configure one web application in IIS, as i know i have to create one web site for my application and assign one application pool.we can set one application pool with different websites.if one ore more website have an issue and stop working in this case my application can work as it is or it will stop.

please suggest me what i have to do create another application pool for my website or use existing.

Comment: if you assign one App Pool for 2 or more web apps then one may affects others

Comment: Yes, there is an effect - for example the App Pool resources will be shared and recycling the App Pool will affect all Web Apps using the pool. However, requests run in separate App Domains in the App Pool - so an App Domain crashing [quickly] will have minimal effect on the App Pool or other Web Apps. However, what will have an effect is one Web App being too slow (i.e. using too many workers) and not leaving any free workers remain for the other Web App - in this case one Web App can starve the entire App Pool.

Comment: thanks user2864740 and  Ganesh_Devlekar for your valuable answer,
now i am going to create another applicationpool for my application